# Make request in the API and calculate on the result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to make a request to the API then make a calculation about the result, I tried something like this:

**file.js**

```
function makeRequest() {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            calcPreco(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "https://dominio/api/produtos.php?pid=10&get=price&billingcycle=monthly", true); // true para asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

function calcPreco(preco) {
    console.log(preco);
    preco = preco.replace(",", ".");
    preco -= 5;
    document.getElementById("vps10off").textContent = preco;
}
```

**index.php**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = makeRequest; 
</script>

<span id="vps10off"></span>
```

Nothing is happening, it is not printing the `<span>` value. what did I do wrong?

Comment: Why are you declaring window.onload to be function makeRequest? You need to call a function that executes that function... `window.onload = function() {makeRequest()}`

Comment: `https://dominio/api/produtos.php` is not a valid domain name, and you're assigning a function to the onload, not calling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not invoking your `makeRequest` function.

Change

```
window.onload = makeRequest;
```

To

```
window.onload = makeRequest();
```

If you need to execute more code when the window loads, set the value of `window.onload` to a function that invokes `makeRequest` along with other code you need to be executed on page load.

```
window.onload = function(){
    makeRequest();
    //other code
}
```